# Is there any QGIS 3.x alternative tool for osmpoly_export plugin?

Tags: qgis-3, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, clip, qgis-2

I used this plugin in QGIS2 for easy defining the area of interest using some vector polygon and then cropping the OSM data with osmctools and the poly file.

However the plugin is QGIS2 only:

> This is QGIS 2.x plugin.
>
> It exports all or selected vector polygons to poly-files used by Osmosis, Osmconvert (and probably other OSM-related tools) for cliping OpenStreetMap data.

plugin source:

https://github.com/nextgis/osmpoly_export

Is there any alternative for QGIS3?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the updated code for QGIS 3.x. It's not in the official repo but in a forked version. Download zip https://github.com/ChrFr/osmpoly_export/archive/master.zip and install plugin from zip

You may prefer using command line tool for Python 3 at https://github.com/smellman/ogr2poly

There is a good list of libraries and tools to import/export from POLY format at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Polygon_Filter_File_Format#Converting_to.2Ffrom_POLY_format